# How to group division in postgresql using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

data rows:

```
id status model  time
1  F      m0     12:00
2  S      m0     13:00
3  F      m0     14:00
4  S      m1     12:00
5  S      m1     13:00
6  S      m1     14:00
```

I want to get fail rate(status =f) group by model,
result will be

```
model    fail_rate
m0       2/3
m1       0/3
```

Can we get the result using sql only?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the result have to look like 2/3 or 0.66 or 66.66%?

Comment: 0.66  is good one, 2/3 just for good understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily, using aggregation:

```
select model,
       avg( (status = 'F')::int ) as fail_rate
from t
group by model;
```

Postgres can convert a boolean expression to a number, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  The average of these values is the rate.

Comment: what does avg means? why not status = 'F' / all ?

Comment: @jamee . . . `avg()` is the aggregation function for "average".  I have not idea what the rest of your comment means.

Comment: I undersand finally, avg is alternative method to get rate, that's very clever, S-Man clarify it

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5ce9dfc6111966c69477fa2157600876)

```
SELECT
    model,
    SUM((status = 'F')::int) || '/' || COUNT(*) AS fail_rate
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY model
```

1. `(status = 'F')` gives `true`, if `status == 'F'`. Otherwise it gives `false`.
2. Casting a type boolean (`true`/`false`) into an int yields in `1` for `true`, `0` for `false`
3. Now you are able to sum up these integers. This gives you the sum of all `1` values, which is the count of all `status == 'F'`
4. `COUNT(*)` gives all records
5. With the string concatenation operator `||` you can create your expected result.

Comment: Your comments is very understandful

Comment: If you liked my answer, please do not forget to upvote. Upvoting is for all answers that are helpful although they might not be the one which solves the problem completely (what the accept is for). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did some research, get my version:

```
SELECT
    model,
    (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'F')::numeric / COUNT(*)) AS fail_rate
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY model
```